# Django allauth error - ImproperlyConfigured - "No module named messagesallauth.account.context_processors"

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I get the following error after the first steps of [django-allauth installation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
Error importing module django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messagesallauth.account.context_processors: "No module named messagesallauth.account.context_processors"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.6.6
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Error importing module django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messagesallauth.account.context_processors: "No module named messagesallauth.account.context_processors"
Exception Location: /home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/miguelfg/workspace/projects/python/tdcp_observatorio',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/projects/python/tdcp_observatorio',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/miguelfg/workspace/python_environments/tdcp_observatorio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Wed, 3 Sep 2014 12:29:34 +0200
```

I have gone through all installation steps, including syncdb or migrate commands, until login the django admin interface and add a Site and Social Apps.

Here parts of my settings file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
    # allauth specific context processors
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'custom_middleware.memory.MemoryUsageMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
)

SITE_ID = 1

...

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

I'm using allauth in another project and I've never got this. Any help is very welcome :-)

Comment: add a `,` after: `'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'`

Comment: Damn it... thanks a lot!, i was soooo blind, hehe